# Helm kubernetes-dashboard install remove repeated works in the pod and service name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am installing dashboard service using helm.  Its create pods and service name like this ***kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard***. How can remove the duplicate ***kubernetes-dashboard*** word from the name.

```
helm install stable/kubernetes-dashboard  --name kubernetes-dashboard --namespace  kube-system
```

output

```
 k get svc  -n kube-system  |grep dashboard
kubernetes-dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard   10.96.114.17     <none>        80/TCP          26m
```

thanks
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can not achieve this without changes in kubernetes-dashboard helm chart.

According this code

```
  _helpers.tpl
  ...
  {{ define "fullname" }}
  {{- $name := default "kubernetes-dashboard" .Values.nameOverride -}}
  {{ printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 -}}
  {{ end }}
  ...

  svc.yaml

  ...
  metadata:
    name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  ...
```

service/pod name is concatenated from release name and "kubernetes-dashboard".

You can adjust "fullname" template to fix this.

Comment: yeah, I was just looking at this, when I give empty sting for name, its generating random string. let me look around how to change the template fullname. thanks for the response